# SonarQube: Manual Upload of coverage report

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

I have managed to produce  a coverage report for a `.NET` core project on a debian container where sonar-scanner resides using [minicover](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover).

It seems however there is no easy way of importing this into SonarQube (minicover is not in the list of [supported coverage tools](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770) and the ones listed do not seem to run on linux platforms).

My question goes to SonarQube and is the following: assuming I have a coverage folder in the form of:

```
-
|
 \ 
  coverage-folder/
  |
   index.html
  |
   src/
```

is there a way for manual upload (e.g. `api` call) to sonarqube server so that it is streamlined in the project's analysis?

...or is it at least possible at some project settings to hard-code the expected form of coverage report?
(couldn't find anything related to the latter on the server's UI)

Using `SonarQube 6.7`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot *update* an existing analysis by any mechanism.

What you should look at is the [Generic Test Data format](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data). Set up a translation into this format and then feed your generic report into your analysis (`/d:sonar.coverageReportPaths=[path to report]`) and you should be good to go.